# Basler Ace Camera Integration with Python

Tags: c#, python, camera, integration

My employer currently has a lot of python code currently written and he wants me to create an application that interacts with this code and controls a Basler Ace Camera. The Basler Ace Cameras only support C, C#, C++ coding languages. What is the easiest way to integrate his Python code with the camera code which I am currently writing in C# because of the .NET framework?

Comment: Interesting library at https://github.com/mabl/PyPylon (uses cython to interface to the C++ library)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there is a python interface availabe for working with and access the features of Basler camera namely pypylon